# Return value with AsyncHttpClient loopj

Tags: android, loopj

I currently using loopj Android Asynchronous loopj to read data from a JSON. This is my code:

```
public class HorariosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String hora_inicio;
    String hora_fin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horarios);

        obtDatosBD();
    }


    private void obtDatosBD(){    

        final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://192.168.0.26/WS_policlinica/horas.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if(statusCode==200){

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));

                        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            hora_inicio = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("FISIO_HORA_INICIO");
                            hora_fin = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("FISIO_HORA_FIN");

                        }

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }}}
```

With this code, i can receive and storage data in onSuccess like hora_inicio and hora_fin. But how is it possible to use those values outside function onSuccess?

Specifically, I want to use those variables in my onCreate, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Make a callback function so you can use values after your `obtDatosBD` method is executed for example to update UI with new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `interface` for example:

```
public interface CallbackInterface {
void onDownloadSuccess(JSONArray jsonArray);
void onDownloadFailed(@NonNull Throwable t);
}
```

Then inside your `Activity` where you download data implement this interface `implements CallbackInterface` after that you will need yo `override` methods `onDownloadSuccess` and `onDownloadFailed`. In your `obtDatosBD()` pas as parameter `CallbackInterface` for example: `obtDatosBD(CallbackInterface callbackInterface)` when you call `obtDatosBD` method in `onCreate` you will need to provide `this` as parameter.

Inside `onSuccess` method you can pass the values to interface method:

```
if(callbackInterface != null)
callbackInterface.onDownloadSuccess(jsonArray);
```

Following same thing inside `onFailure` method with `onDownloadFailed`. Then in methods which you previously `override` you will be able to get values in this case `JSONArray` and do whatever you need with them. I hope this will help and hope this is what you need.